# how is this a group when it is not closed under addition

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Definition(from P276 of Introduction to Homological Algebra by Rotman):

> Let $S = \{E, p, X\}$ and *S'* = {*E', p', X*} be etale-sheaves over a
> space $X$. An etale map *f: S $\to$ S'* is a continuous map *f: *E*
> $\to$ *E'** such that *p'f* = *p* and each *f*|*E$_x$* is a
> homomorphism. Then $\text{Hom}_e$$_t$ is an additive abelian group if we
> define *f + g: E $\to$ E'* by *(f + g)(e) = f(e) + g(e)*.

I am really new to sheaves. How is this a group. I couldn't prove if it is closed under addition: *p'(f+g)(e) = p'(f(e)+g(e))* and then how to proceed as *p'* here is only a continuous map between top spaces? Additionally, how to see that f+g is continuous when it is defined that way?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you are trying to check is that if $f$ and $g$ map each fiber $E_x$ into $E'_x$ then also $f+g$ maps each fiber $E_x$ into $E'_x$. Since $E'_x$ is a group and we have $f(e)\in E'_x$ and $g(e)\in E'_x$ also their sum $f(e)+g(e)$ is in $E'_x$.

Comment: We still need to check $p'(f+g)=p$, i.e. $p'((f+g)(e))=p(e)$. I just rephrased this condition: Let $x=p(e)$, then $p'((f+g)(e))=x$ if and only if $(f+g)(e)\in E'_x$